# GCP Pub/Sub - How to retrieve state from BQ scheduled query

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Big Query scheduled query that triggers a cloud function via pub/sub.

I want the function to read the "state" value from the pub/sub message so I can see if it completed successfully.

The below will always trigger the else statement. If the if statement is removed, it will return a KeyError.

```
import base64

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')

    if 'state' in data:
        state = data['state']
        print("returned state: " + state)
    else:
        print ("No state attribute found")
```

Here is the pubsub message the function should receive:

```
{
"data":
{"dataSourceId": "scheduled_query", 
"destinationDatasetId": "xxxxxxxxxx", 
"emailPreferences": { }, 
"endTime": "2020-03-12T20:40:13.627285Z", 
"errorStatus": { },
"name": "xxxxxxxxxx", "notificationPubsubTopic": "projects/xxxxxxxxxx/topics/xxxxxxxxxx", 
"params": { "destination_table_name_template": "xxxxxxxxxx", "query": "xxxxxxxxxx", "write_disposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE" }, 
"runTime": "2020-03-05T10:00:00Z", 
"scheduleTime": "2020-03-12T20:37:13.17166Z", 
"startTime": "2020-03-12T20:37:13.328479Z", 
"state": "SUCCEEDED", 
"updateTime": "2020-03-12T20:40:13.627307Z", 
"userId": "xxxxxxxxxx"
}
}
```

Comment: Show the `event` data received by your function in your question. What does "doesn't work` mean? An error or one of the messages?

Comment: Hi John, apologies for not being clearer. I've edited my post to include that information.

Comment: Is the update to your question the data actually received or what you think it should be?

Comment: Actually received, obtained by printing to log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out.

```
data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
```

This returns a json formatted string, not a dictionary object. You need to convert to dict via:

```
data_dict = json.loads(data)
```

In order to be able to access it like a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to the python library [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-datatransfer/blob/d10fd6dc77c1987983ada5585a632e7de4d10c44/google/cloud/bigquery_datatransfer_v1/gapic/enums.py#L36)

You have also [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/TransferState)

Eventually, you can check [additional fields added in the JSON notification message](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs.runs#TransferRun)